# Python IRC bot with support for plugins and not command only

Tags: python, irc, bots

I have just made a script in Python which will connect to my MySQL database every XX second and check for new posts on my forum. If there are any new posts, I would like to have the user's of my IRC channel notified.
To do this I need to hook up my script with an IRC bot.
I have been searching around to find an IRC bot which supports plugins which are not only called by commands (e.g. ".google example") as I would like my script to be running constantly and when new posts are found have the bot print a message.

Does anyone know of an IRC bot which would allow me to do that?

Comment: @Fabian The Twisted library seems great for thos. I'll try play around with it. Thank you very much. I'm not sure how to do. Should you leave an answer which I can accept?

Comment: @SimonBS: [hello world IRC bot in twisted with lots of comments](http://www.habnabit.org/twistedex.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always take a look at Twisted, which is supposed to make it very easy for you to create your own IRC bot:

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.0.0/api/twisted.words.protocols.irc.IRC.html

Answer (score 0):

you should easily find a python IRC client library which would let you do (almost) anything you want directly from your python script.

the [Python Package Index (aka. pypi)](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=%2Birc+%2Bclient&submit=search) lists some irc client libraries...

Answer (score 0):

As a kind of shameless plug, I will point to the IRC bot that I have developed with ease of extensibility in mind (via plugins and custom commands):

- http://github.com/Xion/seejoo

While its plugins are generally meant to be driven by IRC events (such as an user joining a channel) and not a time-based "ticks", I think it would be feasible to utilize the "someone said something on channel" (`message`) event as a trigger for your database poll.

If you would like to play with this thing, I recommend looking at [already existing plugins](https://github.com/Xion/seejoo/tree/master/seejoo/plugins) - especially the [`memo`](https://github.com/Xion/seejoo/blob/master/seejoo/plugins/memo.py) one.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Twisted Library as suggested by @Fabian. Following the guide below, you will end up having a good skeleton for an IRC but which is easily extendable with your own plugins.

http://www.eflorenzano.com/blog/post/writing-markov-chain-irc-bot-twisted-and-python/